# Add a message on all views in Django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to use the Django messages framework to show a message to users visiting our website. The idea is to show it on the first page they view and then not show it again for the rest of the user session.

I'm thinking it will work a bit like this:

```
if request.session.get('show_welcome_message', True):
    messages.info(request, 'Welcome to our site!')
    request.session['show_welcome_message'] = False
```

My question is, where's the best place to add this to have it show on all website pages?

And, is there a better way to do something like this that makes use of Django's native messaging to display a message to users that they don't see again on the same session if they close the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/) for this.

---

> The idea is to show it on the first page they view and then not show it again for the rest of the user session.

If your idea of a session is everytime a new browser/tab is opened. This line may not help:
`request.session['show_welcome_message'] = False`

This is because django's session persists event after closing the browser.

I would suggest to use the browser's `SessionStorage` on the client side alongside and some ajax to reliably check whether it's a first time visit.

Comment: Thanks, Kyell. I don't mind people returning to the site in the same session and not seeing the message, as long as they have clicked to close it. It's more important to continue to show the message until it's clicked closed and then not show it again for the same session.

Comment: Well no problem there then. Also, in case you dont know, the messages don't persist after the next request. So might have to keep adding the welcome message on each request then use some ajax request to set the `show_welcome_message` on clicking close.